# What is the best column type to store mixed data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, casting, varbinary, visual-foxpro

We are doing a Visual Foxpro (DBF) to SQL Server conversion, but will retain the VFP GUI to now use the SQL Server database.

In several memo fields in VFP, we store a mix of ASCII characters and text.

What would be the best column datatype to store these values preferably without having to CAST?

Along these same lines, we also have times when we convert Word documents into a Memo file, for these, which field type in SQL Server would work the best?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a particular version of SQL Server that you are targeting?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the version of SQL Server you are using. 2005 and newer support VARCHAR(MAX), which can store strings up to 2GB. Short strings are stored efficiently (in the row) while larger strings are automatically stored in a blob database area, with only a pointer to the blob stored in the row. From a developer's perspective you don't need to worry about this complexity and use VARCHAR(MAX) if your data can exceed 8000 characters.

As for your Word files, it depends if you want to store the actual file (in binary format) in the database or only the content. In the first case you could use VARBINARY(MAX) (or store the file on disk and only the path and other file meta data in SQL Server). If you want to store the actual content you will need to first convert to some suitable format (Rich Text, XML, etc.) and then store that in VARCHAR(MAX).

NOTE: use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR if your data contains unicode characters (rather than just ASCII)

Comment: Also note page limit for `Nvarchar` is 4000 characters due to increased storage requirements for unicode data.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback so far and here is some more info that might help. I am using SQL 2008 R2 and did try using the VarChar(max) field type, but received an error when trying to add the memo text with the embedded ASCII characters.

Comment: I wasn't able to save the msg and when I try to enter the SQL string in the Query Window, it will not accept the Insert code beyond where the embedded ASCII char is..I can't even paste it here. I'll try Altering to a VARBINARY and see if I have better results.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "embedded ASCII." Can you elaborate?

Comment: The ASCII char is embedded within the character string such as "Last name <ascii symbol> etc etc " I also have been trying to create the SQLEXEC command to either Cast or Convert this text/ascii string to a VarBinary and send to SQL, but have not had much luck yet.

Comment: Well, I believe I have it working 99% using the CONVERT(varbinary(max),'MLAWCENDO  ', 0) as an example in my Insert statement, the only issue unresolved is I have some funky ASCII char embedded that just won't convert and I need to research further to see where it is coming from. Appreciate everyone's help..thanks again.